# Camer.takePicture, help me to take picture and save after an acceleration

Tags: android, android-intent

I would save a photo after an acceeleration. This is my code:

```
if (acc_tot > 10.5) {
            camera = Camera.open();
            camera.takePicture(null, null, jpegCallback);

            camera.release();
    }
.....
....
PictureCallback jpegCallback = new PictureCallback() {
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera _camera) {


        }

    };
```

Can you help me? can i save photo in my sdcard?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily. Take a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html) and [this](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/cameradirect.html).
 You can save image to SD card easily. Do this

First add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` this to the manifest.
Now implement your `PictureCallback` like this

```
PictureCallback jpegCallback = new PictureCallback() {
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera _camera) {

String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File myDir = new File(root + "/saved_images");    
    myDir.mkdirs();

    String fname = "ImageName" +".jpg";
    File file = new File (myDir, fname);
    if (file.exists ()) file.delete (); 
    try {
           file.createNewFile();
           FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
           bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
           out.write(data,0,dat.length);
           out.flush();
           out.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
    }

        }

    };
```

Hope this helps

Comment: :( i do it but i don't see the photo

Comment: Image should be inside "/saved_images" directory in your SD card.

Comment: put a Log message on 'onPictureTaken()' to see whether the code is executed. Sometimes camera dies off without executing 'onPictureTaken()'

Comment: Look a i wrote this but i don't see the photo:

    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera arg1) {
         Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data,0,data.length);
         
         String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
            File myDir = new File(root + "/saved_images");    
            myDir.mkdirs();
    
            String fname = "ImageName" +".jpg";
            File file = new File (myDir, fname);

Comment: if (file.exists ()) file.delete (); 
            try {
                   FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                   bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
                   out.flush();
                   out.close();
                   Toast.makeText(SensorActivity.this, 
             "Image saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
            }   
            Toast.makeText(SensorActivity.this, 
           "Error save image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        
       };

Comment: Are there any exceptions occurring?

Comment: can i prove with intent? i expone my purpose, i want take e photo and save it in my folder, but i dn't see the photo while i am in my application. Have you any idea? can you expone your code?

Comment: release camera on 'onDestroy()'. This should solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

You are releasing your camera right after trying to take a picture. That's not guaranteed to work at all - the camera may just shut down and never give you your picture. If you don't want the camera open once you receive your picture, call camera.release() in your picture callback at the earliest, not before.

In addition, you don't start up camera preview, or set a destination for preview frames. Both of these are required before you can take a picture. If you're targeting Android >= 3.0, the following minimal code should work:

```
 import android.graphics.SurfaceTexture;
 ...
 private mSurfaceTexture = new SurfaceTexture(0);
 ...
 if (acc_tot > 10.5) {
        camera = Camera.open();
        camera.setPreviewTexture(mSurfaceTexture);
        camera.startPreview();
        camera.takePicture(null, null, jpegCallback);
 }
```

However, it'll take quite a while for the camera to start up if you do this every time you want a single picture (~1 second).

For good performance, you'll need to open the camera and start preview at the start of your acceleration tracking, so that you can just call takePicture when you need to with minimum delay. Then release the camera device once you're pausing your Activity or stopping acceleration tracking.

Comment: i use android 2.3; what can i do?